# C# manually create window like java's JFrame, JPanel / Canvas & Graphics

Tags: c#

I've worked with Java and was creating an RPG Game, I created a window for the game using JFrame. How can I do this in Visual Studio in C# using code and not with the Design Editor like in Java Eclipse? More specifically how can I create a window using C# in Microsoft Visual Studio like I would using Java in Eclipse? I want to do this because I want to manually draw images and to each pixel of the window and be able to make it fullscreen on a specific screen that can be changed in-game.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are seeking an analog for the JFrame, I presume that by "full screen" you really mean "maximized."

You can get control over the rendering of a Windows Form by overriding its OnPaint() method.  Be careful with your calculations relative to the dimensions of the form.  Also, since you are shirking the IDE and WYSIWYG editor, beware that it will could become difficult to change course later if you decide you want to use the design tools to create toolbars, buttons, etc.  It might make more sense to instead create a form with the WYSIWYG editor and place a Panel onto the form, then create a custom drawing routine on the Panel.  In any event, based on your question as I understand it, here is the minimal code:

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
{
    static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new MyForm());
        }
    }

    public class MyForm : Form
    {
        public MyForm()
        {
            //InitializeComponent();
        }


        protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnPaint(e);

            Graphics gfx = e.Graphics;
            gfx.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, 10f, 10f, 10f, 10f);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can I find a tutorial of this? I'm kind of confused

Comment: In java I can create a borderless maximised window with any name with one class without any window design property files, just the References & Class file. But I am given all these other files. I'd rather do everything they do to the window in code if at all possible. I would go back to using java but I just love the availability of static classes & delegates in this lang. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

It's not so much C# as what framework are you using? For example Windows Forms or WPF? If indifferent, search for "hello world" tutorial on WPF.

Answer (score 0):

You can create windows form application using visual studio templates. Do not compare with other Language IDE, it will just confuse you.