# how can i replace JPanel with c#

Tags: c#, jpanel

I have to develop Monopoly video game, What I want is for all 40 squares to be stored in order in an array list, it seems easy with ( JPanel) I'm just wondering can i do that with c#

```
`
```

Comment: Maybe this can help you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29477358/c-sharp-manually-create-window-like-javas-jframe-jpanel-canvas-graphics

Comment: Tell us what API you are using; ASP.NET? WinForm? UWP? WPF?